# Redirect http server request in Dart, but uri.host is blank

Tags: dart

I've got:

```
server.listen((HttpRequest request) {
      print(request.uri.toString());
      if (request.uri.host == "woven.app") {
        request.response.redirect(new Uri(scheme: 'http', host: 'woven.co',
          path: request.uri.path, fragment: request.uri.fragment));
      }
      ...
```

But line 2 returns blank. According to the notes for `request.uri`:

```
   * Returns the host part of the authority component.
   *
   * Returns the empty string if there is no authority component and
   * hence no host.
```

UPDATE: This is the case locally and on server, tested with Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This properly returns the hostname:

```
request.headers.host
```

Why does this work whereas `request.uri.host` does not?